# Using mlocate to search on multiple systems in parallel

Tags: bash, locate

I often need to search files on different systems, without knowing on which system the file I'm looking for is located.

Is it possible to search with mlocate on multiple systems in parallel? By searching directly in multiple `mlocate.db` files or with some bash magic?

Answer (score 1):

Use bash's `&` to run several 'ssh' commands in parallel, followed by `wait` without parameters to wait for all jobs to finish. For example, assuming you have `$query` and a space-separated list of hosts in `$hosts`:

```
for host in $hosts; do
    ssh $host "locate ${query@Q} | sed 's/^/$host:/'" &
done; wait
```

This is not complete – it doesn't handle interrupts well, and probably has a chance of torn output lines. It should be run as a stand-alone script, *not* as a function (although wrapping it in a `(...)` may work).

For older Bash versions that lack `${var@Q}` (which I think is new in 5.0), use `$(printf %q "$var")`. Both assume that the remote systems also have a login shell that follows sh/bash quoting rules.